# Obter link de uma imagem guardada na bd

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, facebook

Estou a desenvolver um Projecto em ASP.NET MVC usando c#.

Tenho uma página com um botão de partilha com o facebook.

O botão de partilha já está a funcionar, contudo estou com problemas por causa da tag da imagem, pois esta só aceita hyperlink de imagens.

A imagem que quero mostrar está na base de dados e está em formato string(base64).

```
OpenGraphProperties.AddImage("http://odishasuntimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/asteroid.jpg");
```

Este é o método que vai permitir criar a tag og:image. Este método esta a funcionar corretamente porque eu lhe passei o link de uma imagem aleatória que encontrei na net.

Contudo se eu lhe passar uma string de uma imagem que tenho armazenada na BD ele não vai funcionar. Se eu for á página de debug do facebook consigo perceber isso pois lá mostra-me um erro que diz que a tag og:image foi criada de forma incorreta.

O que eu quero é uma maneira de criar um link de uma imagem que tenho armazenada na BD semelhante ao link que está em cima.

Uma coisa que reparei é que se a imagem estiver armazenada na raiz do Projecto, ao invés de estar na BD, por exemplo, numa pasta content/imagens a tag og:image já funciona.

Assim:

```
OpenGraphProperties.AddImage(Url.Content("~/Content/Imagens/User.png"));
```

Como faço para criar um hyperlink da imagem que está armazenada na base de dados ?

Comment: Romeu compartilha conosco o que você já tentou em forma de código e da mais informações da base para conseguirmos entender onde está armazenado a imagem(tabela, coluna) qual base de dados ...

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa expor uma rota em sua aplicação web ou webapi, onde o retorno será essa imagem, então essa rota será o "link" para a sua imagem.

```
    [HttpGet("{idImagem}")]
    [Route("Imagem")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Imagem(int idImagem = 0)
    {
        //Faça sua consulta para obter a string Base64 de sua imagem, que está armazenada no banco.
        string src = "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";

         byte[] data = await Task.Run(() => Convert.FromBase64String(src));

        //utilize o mime correto e nome desejado
        return this.File(data, "image/png", "imagem.png");
    }
```